# SQL Query, Group_Concat of multiple left joins and nested queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm playing around with sql, playing with tutorials on internet, some basic sqlite in an app and have come stuck with the following issue.

I have several tables described below.

Table 1 (Recipe)

```
ID,     Name
1,      Carrot Cake
2,      Cheese Cake
3,      Chocolate Cake
```

Table 2 (Methods)

```
ID,     Method Name,          RecipeID
1,      Old School Method,    1
2,      Low Salt Method,      1
3,      Extra Chocolate,      3
```

Table 3 (Ingredients)

```
ID,      Name,       Quantity,   MethodID
1,       Eggs,       2,          1
2,       Carrots,    1,          1
3,       Flour,      40,         1
4,       Salt,       2,          1
5,       Eggs,       2,          2
6,       Carrots,    1,          2
7,       Flour,      50,         2
8,       Milk,       20,         3
9,       Chocolate,  10,         3
10,      Eggs,       1,          3
```

What i basically want to do is print out a list of recipes, all possible methods, and all ingredients in those methods. If no indigents or methods listed, just show null or be blank.

Step 1:

```
SELECT Recipe.* FROM Recipe
```

obviously prints out

```
id  name
1   Carrot Cake
2   Cheese Cake
3   Chocolate Cake
```

Step 2:

```
SELECT Recipe.*, GROUP_CONCAT(Method.Name) as Methods 
FROM Recipe 
LEFT JOIN Method
ON Method.RecipeID = Recipe.ID
GROUP BY Recipe.id
```

returns

```
id  name            Methods
1   Carrot Cake     Low Salt Method,Old School Method
2   Cheese Cake     (null)
3   Chocolate Cake  Extra Chocolate
```

Which again makes sense, however now i want to list the ingredients and quantity in each method, something like

```
1 Carrot Cake    Low Salt Method (Eggs 2, Carrots 1, Flour 40, Salt 2), Old School Method (.... )
```

The format hasn't got to be the same but just show same information, somehow

Having a quick google, i came across 'nested queries' however I'm struggling to make them work

Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the data in two steps: first ingredients, next methods. 
This requires a subquery:

```
select id, recipename, group_concat(name || ' ' || ingredients)
from (
    select 
        r.id, r.recipename, m.name, 
        '(' || group_concat(i.name || ' ' || i.quantity, ',') || ' )' ingredients
    from recipe r
    left join method m on m.recipeid = r.id
    left join ingredients i on i.methodid = m.id
    group by 1, 2, 3
    ) sub
group by 1, 2;

1 | Carrot Cake   | Low Salt Method ( Carrots 1, Eggs 2, Flour 50 ), Old School Method ( Carrots 1, Eggs 2, Flour 40, Salt 2 )
2 | Cheese Cake   |
3 | Chocolate Cake| Extra Chocolate ( Chocolate 10, Eggs 1, Milk 20 )
```

To better understand how it works, run the inner query:

```
    select 
        r.id, r.recipename, m.name, 
        '(' || group_concat(i.name || ' ' || i.quantity, ',') || ' )' ingredients
    from recipe r
    left join method m on m.recipeid = r.id
    left join ingredients i on i.methodid = m.id
    group by 1, 2, 3;

1 | Carrot Cake   | Low Salt Method   | ( Carrots 1, Eggs 2, Flour 50 )
1 | Carrot Cake   | Old School Method | ( Carrots 1, Eggs 2, Flour 40, Salt 2 )
2 | Cheese Cake   |                   |
3 | Chocolate Cake| Extra Chocolate   | ( Chocolate 10, Eggs 1, Milk 20 )
```

This result set is like a table on which you execute the outer query.